# How to compare the type variable in "is" operator in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I couldn't find a way to store the `Type` value in Map so that I could use it in `is` operator to check the validity of type using this map later on. Also, can `is` operator accept `Type` as a variable?

For eg, Below is hypothetical code solving the problem but it's invalid.

```
Map<String, Type> map = {
"sku": String,
"price": double,
"quantity": int,
};

dynamic value = 10;
if(value is map["quantity"]){
  print("value is of type int and int is expected for quantity value");
}
```

Comment: `value is typeVariable` isn't legal, but you could do `value.runtimeType == typeVariable`.  Note that if inheritance is involved, it' won't work with types of base classes.  This includes abstract classes such as `Map` or `Set` that are actually implemented by private, internal types.

Comment: BTW if your goal is to validate that JSON matches is well-formed according to some schema, I would highly recommend using [`package:built_value`](https://pub.dev/packages/built_value) to serialize to/from JSON and to do error-checking for you.

Comment: Your problem comes from the thinking that the 'is' operator can be used with objects, and it can't. When you do `x is y` y has to be a Type directly, something that can be resolved statically. If this needs to be extracted from a Map (like your example) that wouldn't work because map['quantity'] returns nullable, it can even throw, so, 'is' can't operate with that. The only thing that comes to my mind is to define custom types that simply proxy the ones you already have there. Like `typedef Quantity = int;` and use it as `value is Quantity` but then again, you could simply use int directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
class TypeCheck<T> {
  const TypeCheck();
  bool typeCheck(dynamic value) => value is T;
}

void main() {
  Map<String, TypeCheck> map = {
    "sku": TypeCheck<String>(),
    "price": TypeCheck<double>(),
    "quantity": TypeCheck<int>(),
  };

  dynamic value = 10;
  if (map["quantity"]!.typeCheck(value)) {
    print("value is of type int and int is expected for quantity value");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure I fully understand I understand what you are trying to do but why don't you try something like.

```
bool _validate(Map productDetails){
  if (productDetails.containsKey("sold_individually") && productDetails["sold_individually"] is bool) {
    //return true or false 
  }
  else if (productDetails.containsKey("stock_quantity") && productDetails["stock_quantity"] is int){
//return true or false 
  }
  else if (productDetails.containsKey("tax_class") && productDetails["tax_class"] is String && productDetails["tax_class"].isNotEmpty) {
//return true or false 
   } else {
//return true or false 
   }
}
```

As for the other part of your question you wont get an error but you will always return false. In contrast if you check if a variable is dynamic it will always return true.

Comment: I want to make validation rules for valid data types before getting the values from parsed JSON.
I have to manually write this code every time before getting values from JSON.

 if (productDetails.containsKey("sold_individually") &&
          productDetails["sold_individually"] is bool) 

 if (productDetails.containsKey("stock_quantity") &&
          productDetails["stock_quantity"] is int)

  if (productDetails.containsKey("tax_class") &&
          productDetails["tax_class"] is String &&
          productDetails["tax_class"].isNotEmpty)

Comment: That's not redundant coz it will ensure that the key exist before you want to access it. The network service response can't be trusted and front-end code should be ready for those untrusted response.

Comment: I think I understand better now is why can you just make a validate function like above then call that every time instead?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your end goal. But from what you have, I don't think you are taking advantage of the strongly-typed nature of dart.

- Assuming you are getting your map from an API, you could enforce
  typing manually in your code as follows;

> ```
>  Map<String, Type> map = {
>        "sku": json['key'] as String,
>        "price": json['key'] as double,
>        "quantity": json['key'] as int,
>     };
> ```

And avoid using `dynamic` when declaring variables.

OR

- In the case you have a user-defined type you what to compare, you can use the [equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) package on a class for instance as follows;

> ```
> class CustomMap extends Equatable {
>        String sky;
>        double price;
>        int quantity;
>
>      // here you put the fields of a class you want for two instances of a class to be equal. 
>       @overide 
>       List<Object> get props => [sky, price, quantity]; 
> }
> ```

**Update from your comment**

You should have a custom class for the API objects for instance;

```
class Item extends Equatable {
    String sku;
    double price;
    int quantity;
    
    Item({this.sky, this.price, this.quantity});

  // factory constructor 
  factory Item.fromMap(Map<String, dynmic> json) {
      final sku = json['sku'] as String,
      final price = (json['price'] as num) as double,
      final quantity = json['quantity'] as num,

    return Item(sku: sku, price: price, quantity: quantity);
  }

   // define equatable objects
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [sku, price, quantity];

}
```

Now you can use it as follows;

```
Future<Item> objectsFromService(Map<String, dynamic> json ) async {
    http.Response response = http.get(url);
    if(response.status == 200) {
        final decodedJson = json.decode(response.body);
        return Item.fromJson(decodedJson);
    }else{
       print('Error fetch data');
       return null;
    }

}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I am not using decode function for converting the json response and check for its type for further processing: productData = json.decode(response.body); I don't create the map by myself. Then I just check the type of response using "is" operator to check the response schema and further processing.

Comment: Check the updated answer pls. Raise any issue if you have a problem.

Comment: I am using woocommerce rest API endpoints: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-products

Making a model for such large objects would take ages, especially when they are used once or twice in the application. Instead, I use simplistic json.decode() function for automatic conversion of response and validate the response via "is" operator. But the problem, I am facing is that I can't find the way to use the variable with "is" operator.